# Cant set an array of type char equal to a comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to assign values (within a controller) to variables i have created using a model. One of the variables being an array of type Char. However, when i try to assign its value to a comma; eg: arrayName = { ',' }, the IDE returns an error saying;

" 'char[]' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'char[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Is this because my declaration of the character array is done incorrectly?

My class model (declaring the character array):

```
public class Category

    {

         public char[] delimiterChar { get; set; }

    }
```

My controller (Assigning the value(s) ):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReadCategory()
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            Category passCategory = new Category
            {
                delimiterChar = { ',' },
            };

            return View(passCategory);
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise starting to follow .NET naming conventions, where your property would be called `DelimiterChar` rather than `delimiterChar`. Additionally, the name implies it's just a single character, which would be better expressed as a property of type `char` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: You've been blessed with an answer from Jon Skeet, man! congrats!

Comment: It really is a privilege! Thanks once again Jon. Will make sure to carry your advice into any further projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code currently contains a [*collection initializer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). This:

```cs
Category passCategory = new Category
{
    delimiterChar = { ',' },
};
```

is equivalent to this:

```cs
Category passCategory = new Category();
passCategory.delimiterChar.Add(',');
```

It's not *assigning*. To do that, you need to give a value instead:

```cs
Category passCategory = new Category
{
    delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
};
```